# Rendering Multiple (PartialView) Forms On One View Using @foreach

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, mvvm, asp.net-mvc-5

Say I've got five different unique forms (i.e. Form1, Form2, etc.), and a View called **ManyForms**.  Each of the five forms has its own PartialView (call them **_Form1**, **_Form2**, etc.)

I want to be able to render these PartialViews on **ManyForms**, and I know I can use `@Html.RenderPartial` to do this.

However, I want to be able to dynamically render multiple forms on the **ManyForms** view (say, for instance, three **_Form3**s, two **_Form4**s, and one **_Form5**).

Does my case warrant the usage of `@foreach`?  If so, how would I use `@foreach` to accomplish this, and what (roughly speaking) should the ViewModel look like - assuming that I might face some very annoying dictionary errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up getting this working using a ViewModel that looks something like this:

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    public List<Form1> Form1{ get; set; }
    public List<Form2> Form2 { get; set; }
    public List<Form3> Form3{ get; set; }
    // etc.

    public MainViewModel() {

        Form1 = new List<Form1>();
        Form2 = new List<Form2>();
        Form3 = new List<Form3>();
        // etc.
}
```

And on the **ManyForms** View:

```
@model Forms.Models.ViewModels.MainViewModel

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div id="MainFormAccordion">

        @foreach (var x in Model.Form1.ToList())
        {
            Html.RenderPartial("_Form1", x);
        }

        @foreach (var x in Model.Form2.ToList())
        {
            Html.RenderPartial("_Form2", x);
        }

// etc.
```

The **_Form** PartialViews each use as their models `MainViewModel.FormX`.  I don't know if I am following good practices here, but I guess this is how one could get it working with `@foreach`.